# multithread programming in SharePoint 2007

Tags: multithreading, sharepoint-2007, moss

I have created a console application which goes through all site collections and thier sub sites and all lists and moves all documents from one farm to another. but because the number of documents is very huge it takes very long time to do whole task. 
Now I am wondering about creating a new thread för each site collection. is it a good solution and what is the best way to accomplish it.

thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thread per site collection? That would be awful for large numbers of site collections.  What would work better is a thread pool approach that serviced a queue of job objects...one per site collection url. Then you would have a relatively small number of worker threads servicing the queue.